# Mask RCNN 1 class only

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision, object-detection

I am looking to use only one class, person (along with BG, background), for the Mask RCNN object detection. I am using this link: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN to run the mask rcnn. Is there a specific way to complete this (editing specific files, creating an extra python file, or just by filtering selections from the class_names array)? Any direction or solution will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've trained the same repo for sheeps. You have to do 2 things:

1. Change the train and inference class numbers as 1 + 1 ( bg and person ):

   ```
    class SheepsConfig(Config):

        NAME = "sheeps"
        NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1 # background + sheep

    config = SheepsConfig()  # Don't forget to use this config while creating your model
    config.display()
   ```
2. You need to create dataset to train on. You can use coco as follows:

   ```
    import coco
    from pycocotools.coco import COCO

    ct = COCO("/YourPathToCocoDataset/annotations/instances_train2014.json")
    ct.getCatIds(['sheep']) 
    # Sheep class' id is 20. You should run for person and use that id

    COCO_DIR = "/YourPathToCocoDataset/"
    # This path has train2014, annotations and val2014 files in it

    # Training dataset
    dataset_train = coco.CocoDataset()
    dataset_train.load_coco(COCO_DIR, "train", class_ids=[20])
    dataset_train.prepare()

    # Validation dataset
    dataset_val = coco.CocoDataset()
    dataset_val.load_coco(COCO_DIR, "val", class_ids=[20])
    dataset_val.prepare()
   ```

And then simply create your model as:

```
# Create model in training mode
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=config, model_dir=MODEL_DIR)
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
# This COCO_MODEL_PATH is the path to the mask_rcnn_coco.h5 file in this repo
```

Then you can train it with this code:

```
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
        learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, 
        epochs=100, 
        layers='heads')#You can also use 'all' to train all network.
```

Don't forget to use tensorflow 1.x and keras 2.1.0 :) I can train with these versions.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow what @dnl_anoj suggested "showing results of only person classes". I removed all classes but the person class from the predicted results . You can use the following code in `run_on_opencv_image()` function in the `predictor.py` file in https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.

```
predictions = self.coco_demo.compute_prediction(image)
top_predictions = self.coco_demo.select_top_predictions(predictions)

masks = top_predictions.get_field("mask")
boxes = top_predictions.bbox
label_indexs = top_predictions.get_field("labels").numpy()

x = np.where(label_indexs != 1) # get indexes of labels which are not person

#remove items which are not person class
masks = np.delete(masks,x, axis=0)
boxes = np.delete(boxes,x, axis=0)
label_indexs = np.delete(label_indexs,x)
labels = self.convert_label_index_to_string(label_indexs)
```

Comment: that file doesn't exist in the linked repo. which file did you edit?

Answer (score 0):

There is a balloon example made by the author of the github you linked which is very well written and contains only one class (balloons) you should follow this tutorial: https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46

Comment: So the program already pretrains the 'person' class. Is there no way to filter the detections so that only 'person' is detected and not the other classes? Would we specifically have to create another dataset to pretrain?

Comment: Oh sorry I had misunderstood your question. Some notebooks are available in the Mask RCNN repo look at this one for instance: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/coco/inspect_data.ipynb
It helps to visualize the results of the model on a random image. The classes detected are represented with their ID wich you can see in the result of the third cell. 'Person' has ID = 1 so it shouldn't be a problem to select only the masks or boxes with ID=1!

Comment: I would add to my comment that if your only wish is to detect people you can use object detection models like YOLO which are faster and quite reliable. In particular OpenCV has an implementation which would be easier to use than the Mask RCNN I suppose: https://www.data-stats.com/person-detection-using-yolo-and-opencv/

Comment: so i essentially want to create white silhouettes of people (in black background). Not too sure about yolo since it creates bounding boxes for detections. it'll make the silhouette creation process slightly complicated

Comment: Mask RCNN is perfect for that then.

Comment: dnl_anoj could you possibly provide an example code for the second comment (selecting masks through specifying the id). I am not unable to get an output image with just mask only on 'person' in the image