# Selecting a specific mask from Mask RCNN results, r. Filtering a dictionary to only keep key where r['class_ids']==1

Tags: python, dictionary, mask

This is the closest question to the issue I have now:
[Mask RCNN 1 class only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810714/mask-rcnn-1-class-only)

Mask RCNN returns a dictionary, r, that looks like:

```
{'rois': array([[ 17,   0, 371, 300],
        [323, 107, 374, 153]]),
 'class_ids': array([ 1, 28]),
 'scores': array([0.9999876 , 0.77787864], dtype=float32),
 'masks': array([[[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         ...,
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],
 
        [[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         ...,
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]],
 
        [[False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         ...,
         [False, False],
         [False, False],
         [False, False]]])}
```

I only want to keep masks for the person class (class_ids == 1)

I tried to filter the dictionary by

```
filtered = {k: v for k, v in r.items() if (r['class_ids'] == 1)}
```

This resulted in the following ValueError

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I tried again

```
filtered = {k: v for k, v in r.items() if (r['class_ids'] == 1).any()}
```

This does not filter out anything. a.all() returns and empty dictionary. I am pretty confused how to do this.

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanding, the r['masks'] array contains arrays for each possible class in the model. Used COCO as the base model. The person class has the index 1. So you can get the person mask by using

```
person_mask = r['masks'][:][1]
```

However, in my use case, it did not help much. because I wanted to place the person mask onto a white background. The original image read with skimage.io.imread has the shape (x, y, z) and person_mask has the shape (y, z) so it would be best to not filter r['masks'], which has shape (x, y, z), beforehand.
r['masks'] with shape (x, y, z) where z is the number of masks found in an image - for example it could be a mask of a person (index 1) and a mask of a tie (index 28). Usually, it is safe to assume that the first mask would be the mask of a person, which is why we can transform the original image to only keeping the area of the person mask by using

```
temp[:,:,j] = temp[:,:,j] * r['masks'][:,:,0]
```

The full code is below

```
temp = skimage.io.imread('05a.jpg')
for j in range(temp.shape[2]):
    temp[:,:,j] = temp[:,:,j] * r['masks'][:,:,0]
    background = np.zeros_like(temp)
    background[:,:,:]  = (255, 255, 255)
    rows,cols,channels = temp.shape
    roi = background[0:rows, 0:cols]

    temp = cv.cvtColor(temp,cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img2gray = cv.cvtColor(temp,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, mask = cv.threshold(img2gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask_inv = cv.bitwise_not(mask)

    img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

    img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(temp,temp,mask = mask)

    dst = cv.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
    background[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
    cv.imwrite('res.jpg', background)
```